# Limit of the absolute value of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was just wondering if there is any book that has mentioned that there is a theorem which is like: Let $a = (a(1),a(2),....)$ be a sequence, and for $ i \in \mathbb{N}$, $a(i) \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n| = 0 \iff \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0 $$
Thank you so much!

Comment: $$|a_n|=\sqrt{\left(\text{Re}(a_n)\right)^2+\left(\text{Im}(a_n)\right)^2}$$

Comment: or $||a_n|-0| = |a_n|$, so $||a_n|-0|<\epsilon \implies |a_n - 0| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

This is true.  Polar avails.  Write $z=re^{i\theta}$.  Then $z\to0\iff r\to0$.

One direction is obvious. The other, almost as obvious.  For, if $r\to0$, then $re^{i\theta}$ is on ever smaller circles centered at zero, so that one can easily get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Brown and Churchill might have it, but it's not terribly hard to show.  Assume $a_n \rightarrow 0$.  Then there exists an $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that

$$||a_n|-0|=||a_n|| \\
=|a_n| \\
=|a_n-0|\\
<\varepsilon.$$

So $|a_n| \rightarrow 0$.  Likewise $|a_n| \rightarrow 0$ implies that there exists some $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that

$$|a_n-0|=|a_n| \\
=||a_n|| \\
=||a_n|-0| \\
<\varepsilon.$$

So $a_n \rightarrow 0$.